# IndexError - Using Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, boolean

I'm trying to write a code for a small program that takes a list as an input and returns a Boolean indicating whether there are any consecutively repeated numbers (the list must have at least 2 elements). I keep getting the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

Any advice on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated!

```
def two_length_run(n):

    i = 0

    while i < len(n):
        if len(n) >= 2:
            if (n[i] == n[i + 1]) and (n[i + 1] <= len(n)):
                return True
            else:
                i = i + 1
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: The problem is in 2nd if condition.  if  i+ 1 < len(n) and (n[i] == n[i + 1]) and (n[i + 1] <= len(n)):

Comment: @emlauren You're going through `i` up to `len(n)`.  What do you think will happen when you look at `n[i + 1]` when `i` is at its greatest value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Checking the next element against the length of the list doesn't help; you need to check the next *index* ...
2. ... and do this *before* you access the elements.
3. You need to to keep it from going out of bounds.  A list of length `k` has indices 0:(k-1), but your test allows `i+1` to run to the value of `k`, which causes your access to be out of bounds.

New check: note the change from `<=` to `<`, and reversing the order.

```
if i + 1 < len(n) and n[i] == n[i+1]:
```

"Short-circuiting" ensures that if the first condition is false, the second will no be evaluated.

You can do this more easily with a `for` loop, which helps keep your idex in bounds:

```
if len(n) >= 2:

    for i in range(len(n)-1):
        if n[i] == n[i + 1]:
            return True           # Exit early if you find a pair

return False
```

Comment: You may want to link documentation on `range` for OP. The `for` loop is a good solution (and avoids the possibility of forgetting to increment `i`)

Comment: @Prune This explanation was super helpful - thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
def two_length_run(n):
    if not n or len(n) < 2:
        return False
    for i in xrange(len(n) - 1):
        if n[i] == n[i+1]:
            return True 
    return False
```

Doing the checks(fast exits) before starting to iterate and using xrange instead of having to increment the "i" by hand.

Comment: Error checks?? What is this, production code? :) In seriousness, good checks and easy to read and understand (though the behavior of `range`/`xrange` in not including the max value in the expanded range may be unintuitive to new coders).

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_length_run(n):
    i = 0
    while i < len(n):
        if len(n) >= 2:
            if (i + 1 < len( n )) and ( n[i] == n[i + 1]) and (n[i + 1] <= len(n)):
                return True
            else:
                i = i + 1
        else:
            return False
```

The inner if condition may overflow due to i + 1 when i = len( n ) - 1, so add a check there.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop checks both the current index and the next index, so your `while` condition is incorrect.

Instead of

```
while i < len(n):
    if len(n) >= 2:
```

Using

```
if len(n) > 1:
    while i < len(n) - 1:
        if n[i] == n[i + 1]:
            return True
        i = i + 1

# Checked every index of n without a duplicate
return False
```

Will avoid this index error.

Answer (score 0):

The answers you have gotten seems to be right. However, I think it's cleaner to put the condition in the while statement.

```
def two_length_run(n):

    i = 0

    while i < len(n) - 1:
        if len(n) >= 2:
            if (n[i] == n[i + 1]) and (n[i + 1] <= len(n)):
                return True
            else:
                i = i + 1
        else:
            return False
```

I think that should work